# Facebook Like button for mobile web

Tags: facebook, webkit, facebook-like

Is there a way to add the Facebook Like button on mobile web? (iPhone & Android only is ok)
Is there any mobile sites out there that already do that? Would love to see it in action.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [this tool](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like).

Comment: pkaeding, I'm not sure that teepusink has heard of HTML.

Comment: I need to know the answer too. currently if you put a like button in a mobile web for phone, if the user is not logged in, it will render full facebook login page which is completely not friendly in small screen. Is there a way to put a like button for mobile web, so that if user not logged in it will trigger a mobile login designed for small screen?

Comment: While that tool is helpful, and answers the most basic premise of the question, it is just the standard Like button tool, and this question was specifically asking about mobile web.  There is no optimized Like button for mobile browsers yet, and as @dunforget mentions, the experience for the user can be very bad when using the standard Like button on a mobile website.

Comment: From my testing, that tool doesn't not provide a mobile friendly like button. It simply doesn't work for mobile, even if you are logging in to Facebook via your browser.

Comment: This is such an obnoxious answer.  "This tool" is terrible for mobile support.  It's a real shame this is the accepted answer.  Please look at "this tool" instead: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/bringing-like-to-mobile/ ...  I don't down vote on SO often, but when I do it's because of a response like this...

Comment: You can also use standard OG.like code with display set to "touch" if you're OK with a simple implementation.

Comment: This is not a mobile solution

Answer (score 4):

Does the standard method of adding the Like button to a web page not work for mobile browsers?  I have never tried it, but I would think it should work fine.  If that is not the case, could you elaborate why that won't work?

Comment: If the user is not logged in, which is common on a mobile device where people use facebook apps more often, then they have to authenticate with facebook using the full facebook website, rather than the mobile and/or touch site, so its more cumbersome!

Comment: @Alex, I understand what you are saying, but is there a way around it?  Could the Facebook App handle the click to 'Like' links (via intents, or some other mechanism)?

Comment: @pkaeding there is no way I have seen yet to make the Like button work better on the mobile web.  It does "work", but only works well if the user is already logged into their Facebook account in their mobile browser, which is unlikely (more likely to be using the Facebook app.)

And if the user isn't logged in, the authentication method ends (at least in my experience) in a blank white screen with the original website lost to the user.  Not a very good experience for the user  and the user is no longer on the website.  Bad for both parties.

Comment: @Alex I reported a bug regarding that issue 2 months ago. They assigned this and set priority to Medium, but it never seem to get fixed. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266544906769261